# Alternativa a la query '$where' en MongoDb para buscar documentos que pertenecen a una colección?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Tengo dos colecciones. Una es `lists` y otra es `tasks` Cada "task" pertenece a una "list"

Entonces necesito una ruta GET para obtener todas las `tasks` que pertenecen a una list en concreto. Las puedo obtener exitosamente pasándole el id de referencia:

```
Task.find({
    $where: function () {
        return this.list == '5dc090a09def6d28309ced5b'
    }
```

El problema es que he puesto el id manualmente. Lo que necesito evidentemente es que este puesto como una variable:

```js
app.get('/tasks/:idList', (req, res) => {

    Task.find({
        $where: function () {
            return this.list == req.params.idList
        }
    })
```

El problema es que `req.params.idList` no es accesible desde ahí. Alguna alternativa a este enfoque, teniendo en cuenta que mis Schemas están hecho de la siguiente manera?

```js
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: true
    },
    doned: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    list: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'list',
        required: true
    }
})


const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: [true, 'debes escribir un titulo']
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
})
```

Debería quizás hacerlo al revés?

Comment: haber si entendi, la variable req, no la encuentra en el nivel del where, cierto ?
Podrias declarar una variable a nivel superior `const idList = req.params.idList`

Tambien podrias usar `Task.find({'list': req.params.idList})`

Comment: Lo he intenté. Tampoco puede acceder a las variables. Debe ser una particularidad del método, por lo que pone en los docs de mongo si lo entendí bien. Pero igualmente me sirvió lo otro que me comentaste! Gracias, no imaginé que sería tan sencillo.